# Create a hierarchical foreign key to Identity 3 ApplicationUser:IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

I am using `Identity 3` in `ASP.NET 5 RC1/Core`

I need to create a foreign key reference in the ApplicationUser that refers to the primary key of the ApplicationUser(IdentityUser) using  `EF Code First`.

I have tried

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Column("fk_LineManagerUserId")]
    public Guid LineManagerUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LineManagerUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser LineManagerUser { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Column("fk_LineManagerUserId")]
    public string LineManagerUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LineManagerUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser LineManagerUser { get; set; }
}
```

but I get

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ApplicationUser_ApplicationUser_LineManagerUserId' on table 'AspNetUs
>   ers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.